# Is $\sin(5x)$ uniformly continuous?

Tags: calculus, continuity

My question is, how can I prove that $\sin(5x)$ is not uniformly continuous?

Comment: By Heine-Cantor, it is uniformly continuous on $[-\pi/5, \pi/5]$ and since it is periodic, this would imply it is uniformly continuous on $\mathbf{R}$ in a rather standard proof.

Comment: It is $5$-Lipschitz.